# Using openmp for nested loops of varying iteration sizes

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested, openmp, load-balancing

I have an array of constant, small size (specifically the number of threads used) containing int vectors of varying sizes. The workload that each nested iteration will execute varies too, from almost insignificant to relatively heavy (but usually not too heavy). The code looks like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_of_threads; ++i) 
    for (int j = 0; j = array[i].size(); ++j)
        doStuff(array[i][j]);
```

As I see it there is no easy way to collapse it and let openmp know the real size of the tasks at hand, since the nested loop's size can vary. So no matter my scheduling policy I worry for cases like the following:

The array contains 3 vectors of sizes 8, 8 and 48 respectively and 3 threads working. As I understand it, the scheduler will first make a decision for the 8 tasks then for the other 8 and finally for the 48.

Is there an effective way, **without flattening the array**, to let the scheduler of openmp know to load balance 64 tasks instead of what I previously described?

Comment: 1st step might be to tell us what deficiencies you demonstrated when you test schedule and chunk settings e.g. by adding schedule(runtime) and setting omp_schedule. If you don't have numa affinity requirements this may be sufficient.

Comment: Depending on the input both the workload and the total task size can change. It seems that the best results are produced using the guided scheduling. For 14 threads in a dataset that I expect the total task size to be relatively big I get a x10 speedup whereas in a datataset that I expect the total task size to be small a x3. But my question is if in principle its better to know the full task size (a reason of using the collapse keyword when its possible is exactly that) to do the sceduling is there an efficient way to do it in a case like the one I described?